# link from page two not going back to id on previous page in firefox, see code below. works in IE, O, Saf and Chrome

Tags: css, html

index.html code

```
<!-- SOLUTIONS SECTION -->
<section class="parallax-section" id="solutions">
content of this section
</section>
```

The solutions.html pages needs to link back to index.html#solutions link works fine on IE,Opera, safari and Chrome.

```
<nav id="navigation_basic">
<a href="index.html#solutions"><img src="images/value_images/main_back_button.png"   width="221" height="30" border="0" /></a> 
</nav>'
```

Comment: Please explain (with code and with whole sentences) what you want it to behave and what does not work!

Comment: Hi Sorry man new with these posts. basically when someone clicks on index.html#solutions on page two, I need it to go to section id="solutions" on the index.html page. currently the link works on all browswers except in firefox. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linkable element (the `<section>` in your example) should be an `<a>` element ('a' actually stands for 'anchor').

You can either change your `<section>` to be an `<a>` element, or just include a `<a>` element within your `<section>`, and give the `<a>` element the proper `id="solutions"` attribute.

Comment: hi Ronen thank you for the help. I tried that and still have an issue. what I also tried was javascript:history.back(-1) link on page 2 which work and it goes back to the exact spot (solutions)but my one concern is if the user came direcly to the page (page 2) to from google. would there be a way utilise this further as direct link to indexhtml page